# Strip "\n" from a multiline sting, except when inline

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, newline

If I have a multiline string that contains "\n" as part of the text itself, for example:

```
python_text = """
@commands.command()
def multi():
    print("Three\nLines\nHere")
"""
```

How can I remove all newlines except those in the text itself? I've tried creating a list with `splitlines()` but the multiline string will also be split on the `\n`'s in the text itself. Using `splitlines(True)` in combination with `strip()` doesn't work for the same reasons.

```
print(python_text.splitlines())
```

Output (formatted):

```
[
'@commands.command()', 
'def multi():', 
'    print("Three', 
'Lines', 
'Here")'
]
```

Whilst my desired output is:

```
[
'@commands.command()', 
'def multi():', 
'    print("Three\nLines\nHere")'
]
```

(Or a multiline string print instead of list print, but in the same format)

Is there any way I can only strip the 'trailing' newline characters from a multiline string?
If anything is unclear please let me know and I'll try to explain further.

Edit: Corrected explanation about `splitlines()` and `strip()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape your newlines. In this case you can just make it a raw string literal:

```
python_text = r"""
@commands.command()
def multi():
    print("Three\nLines\nHere")
"""

print(python_text.splitlines())
>>>['', '@commands.command()', 'def multi():', '    print("Three\\nLines\\nHere")']
```

Comment: Ah, I did try to escape them with `replace("\n", "\\n")` but that replaces the newlines at the end of the lines too, whereas the raw string literal doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help :)